# should I overload == operator when I use STL sets?

Tags: c++, stl

When I want to use STL sets to store custom objects in C++,There are many people says:you should  overload < operator,but if I want use find() method, I think it may use == operator to acheive that.Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: P.S. Don't call it STL, call it the standard library or `std::`. The term has some ambiguity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Standard Library* `set::find` uses *equivalence* instead of *equality* to find values. You don't need to provide `operator ==`, just `operator <` (or whatever comparison operator you specified for `set`, `std::less` being the default).

If you are wondering how your element would be found, then assuming the default ordering `find(x)` would return the element `e` for which:

```
!( x < e || e < x )
```

Comment: Correct. Because `set`/`map` are usually implemented as RBTrees. So `operator <` is essential for the correct placement of nodes.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: _RBTrees_ are an implementation detail, and have nothing to do with the fact that ordered sequences work with _equivalence_ and not _equality_.

Comment: Yeah, of course. But one really follows the other. How would you implement a binary search tree without `operator <` or `operator >`? I mean, at face value it's not really important, but it can help you see the motivation behind the spec.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: Yes, one follows the other, but is the other way around.

Comment: So you're saying that the decision to implement ordered containers as binary search trees was based on the fact that the spec requires strict weak ordering? Something tells me that it was specified this way because it was intended for them to be easily implemented as binary search trees.

Comment: @antony-arnold: I'm saying that ordered sequences where specified to be based on a strict weak ordering. The specification was carefully written to not disallow rb-trees as an implementation (note the double negative).

Comment: Just pointing out that with DeMorgan's Laws, your implementation becomes `!(x < e || e < x)`, which might be a bit easier on the eyes.

Comment: @K-ballo: Right. So we agree then... :S

Answer (score 1):

Since `std::set`s require something that specifies a *strict weak ordering*. `operator==` is insufficient for this task.

You should overload `operator<` only if it makes sense for the class. If it doesn't, far better would be utilizing the fact that `std::set` has as a second template parameter `Compare`. Hence, defining a comparison struct/function and passing this as the 2nd parameter of your set is another, generally preferable option.

The final option is to specialize `std::less` for your type. For example:

```
namespace std
{ 
    template <>
    struct less<CustomClass>
    { ... };
}
```

Comment: Red-black trees are an implementation detail, and behavior is not based in implementation details. Implementation details are based on behavior.

Comment: Thus the *generally* in brackets. Nothing I've said presumes this anyway. However they're implemented, they require strict weak ordering.

Comment: Since ordered sequences require a strict weak ordering, they are (generally) implemented as a red-black tree. That would be right, but is not what you are saying

Comment: Fair enough, I see your objection. I've reworded it.

Answer (score 1):

Most Standard Library algorithms and containers use operator< (or a comparison function you provide such that it returns true if the lhs element is smaller) for ordering and searching. Algorithms for use with unordered containers will use operator==.

For example, std::lower_bound() will either return the first element matching the search criteria from a sorted container, the largest element still smaller than the search term if the exact term is not found, or an iterator to the end of the container if no element is larger than what you searched for. It does this with operator<, no other operator is required. It takes a number of operations in the order of log(n).

Every other comparison operator (>, >=, <=), with the exception of != and ==, can be derived from operator<.

std::find, however, requires that the type used be Equality Comparable. You can find the reference here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

So if you're working with ordered elements, you need operator<. If you are working with unordered elements, you need operator==.

Comment: `==` can actually be derived from `<`: `return !(a < b || b < a);`

Comment: @chris, that might be true for simple types, but it's easy to generate cases where that doesn't hold.

Comment: Correction: not going to be used by the standard library unless you use `unordered_set` or `unordered_map`.

Comment: Um, no, that first sentence is too strong. For example, the algorithm `std::find` uses `operator==`.

Comment: @chris To expand on Mark Ransom's point, that only holds for elements that can be ordered. The operators == and != can be used on elements where > and < would not make sense. For example, complex numbers.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah, I mixed it up with std::search, you are right. Will edit.

Comment: "though they're generally slower since they can't take advantage of the fact that the container is ordered" -- on the contrary, ordering and searching in unordered containers is typically faster than in ordered containers, because unordered containers are designed to use some form of hashing, which, in a properly managed container with a good hash function, gives O(1) insertion and lookup.

Comment: @PeteBecker I did say generally. If you use std::find on a std::vector or std::list, you'll have a linear search time. Using hashed containers would lower that to constant, at the expense of requiring more memory. Given the complexity of the subject, I'll remove the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

`set`, `map`, `multiset` and `multimap` use only the comparison function you give them, which defaults to `std::less`, which is generally `operator<`. The unordered version in C++11 have a more complex protocol; they don't need an order comparison (they're *unordered*) but they need both equality and hash.

This is also true of all of the standard algorithms which involve ordering (`sort`, `nth_element`, `lower_bound`, `binary_search`, etc.). However, the `find` *algorithm* (and other similar algorithms, such as `count`, `search`, `mismatch`, etc., do require an equality function, defaulting to `operator==`. No standard library algorithm requires both.

Since you specifically asked about the `find` member function, the answer would be that the `set` and all member functions will work fine with just order comparison.

Still, it's almost always a good idea to define all comparison operators if you're going to define `operator<`.